# Stuck on this OpenIddict issue while validation with client creadentials token

Tags: c#, openiddict

> System.InvalidOperationException: An identity cannot be extracted from this request.
>
> This generally indicates that the OpenIddict server stack was asked to validate a token for an endpoint it doesn't manage.
>
> To validate tokens received by custom API endpoints, the OpenIddict validation handler (e.g OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme or OpenIddictValidationOwinDefaults.AuthenticationType) must be used instead.
>
> at OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers.ValidateAuthenticationDemand.HandleAsync(ProcessAuthenticationContext context)
> at OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher.DispatchAsync[TContext](TContext context)
> at OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher.DispatchAsync[TContext](TContext context)
> at OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7174
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
:method: GET
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlYyUERaNl9RUjRfNFo0Q1VMUkUwWFdRRU1KNFVDT0VGSjNDQldTQUQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJwb3N0bWFuIiwic29tZS1jbGFpbSI6InNvbWUtdmFsdWUiLCJvaV9wcnN0IjoicG9zdG1hbiIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InBvc3RtYW4iLCJvaV90a25faWQiOiI3NGE3ZGNlMC1kNjJkLTRmZjQtYjg1MS1kMjRjN2E1OGIwNTEiLCJzY29wZSI6ImFwaSIsImV4cCI6MTY3MjIxMjQzMywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NzE3NC8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NzIyMDg4MzN9.bls8ceNA9bU-xr1-9huV4LDqifX7KDn8E1bqGPGeeWh9ePeN1mYnywFC6lPVls8OtCmtm1v9iTnnfaoZ3r2v_IoKahl727B4QD8AkKpy_8ExiBBECtX9HqDid3w0c8dYS1Rka2xyh5mcKJzlqNlSucNbRqj7Hu8wisizV89K45qmWBsZTIsBqJOR5DKDjVzAEmAvjccD8Hb9kjF6lSiis2E7x41YO0dB4ugc5gEm1huEI44bps7qj9V2mQ70EcNi74KgK3Y57JsityV1Oqjv14gour2jjvccATtLhOtNisUfbw10jPlRj3AT1XiHDjjIhR5pb0z6XTJRblpmNt8wNQ
Referer: https://localhost:7174/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Does anyone know about this? Please tell me the solution

Comment: What was your solution in the end?  You haven't accepted the answer - did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the exception, `OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is the correct authentication scheme to use when you want to validate tokens received by your own APIs.

If you decorated your API endpoint with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`, replace that by `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`.

Comment: What if I have this attribute but I still get the same error?